# .htaccess 301 redirect doesn't work due to question mark symbol "?"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am using the following code to my oldsite to 301 redirect all the traffic to my new website.

> .htaccess  - Located in oldsite.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newsite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

The above .htaccess code works ONLY if the url doesnt contain the question mask symbol "?".

E.g.

**Example 1 is OK**

> http://oldsite.com/whatever
>   ->301 Redirect to  http://newsite.com/

However, If I am going to enter:

**Example 2 is NOT OK**

> http://oldsite.com/?whatever
>   ->301 Redirect to  http://newsite.com/?whatever

it should redirect to index site, like that

> http://oldsite.com/?whatever
>   ->301 Redirect to  http://newsite.com/

and

**Example 3 is NOT OK**

> http://oldsite.com/whatever?something
>   ->301 Redirect to  http://newsite.com/?something

it should redirect to index site, like that

> http://oldsite.com/whatever?something
>   ->301 Redirect to  http://newsite.com/

- Why is that happend ?

and

- how can I face that issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the redirect and rewrite rules are redundant. use your rules like this. To remove the `query string` you need to add a question mark at the end of the rewriterule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newsite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```